# ¿Como restar horas de un DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

Tengo un DateTime y necesito restar horas de una columna a la otra. Por ejemplo, quiero restar `12:45:00 - 12:25:00` y que el resultado sea `20`.

Este el codigo que estoy usando

```
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            DateTime fecha1 = Convert.ToDateTime(inicio[i].ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
            DateTime fecha2 = Convert.ToDateTime(arrayhrllegada[i].ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
            //var duration = Math.Round(fecha1 - fecha2, 1);
            double horas = Math.Round(fecha2.Subtract(fecha1).TotalMinutes,1);

            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = horas.ToString();
        }
```

[image: Es Inicio menos Llegada y el resultado es Tiempo de Espera]

Es Inicio menos Llegada y el resultado es Tiempo de Espera

Comment: a que te refieres por columna ?

Comment: Porque almacenas un horario en un `DateTime` y no en un `TimeSpan`?

Comment: No está clara tu pregunta. Para restar puedes usar el operador `- ` o `Substract`. La cuestión es...que resultado quieres? Quieres los minutos, las horas, los dias? si restas `13:45:00` menos `12:25:00`, que resultado esperas?

Comment: @Pikoh Necesito que el resultado sea 80. Preguntaras, por que? Pues tengo que restar las horas, que es igual a 1htr =60 minutos, y 45 minutos menos 25 minutos nos dan 20. Haciendo la suma, es un total de 80 minutos.

Comment: las variables inicio y arrayhrllegada de que tipo son? porque si son Datetime no necesitas esa conversion puedes restarlas directamente arrayhrllegada[i].Subtract(inicio[i])

Comment: Ya lo hice justamente como me dices, adjuntare una captura sobre los resultados.

Comment: En ese caso,resta,y del resultado (que es un timespan) prueba con la propiedad [TotalMinutes](https://www.elmundo.es/madrid/2018/12/14/5c12b5ac21efa0ca1c8b45fe.html)

Comment: Igual sigue sin funcionar, pero muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: A ver..yo creo que tu problema está en otro lado. Prueba este código: `DateTime fecha1 = Convert.ToDateTime("12:25:00");
            DateTime fecha2 = Convert.ToDateTime("13:45:00");
            double horassss = Math.Round(fecha2.Subtract(fecha1).TotalMinutes, 1);`. Verás como el resultado es 80, que es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 4):

Para restar fechas puedes usar el `Subtract()` del `DateTime`

[DateTime.Subtract Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netframework-4.7.2)

un ejemplo seria

```
DateTime fecha1 = Convert.ToDatetime("12:45:00");
DateTime fecha2 = Convert.ToDatetime("12:25:00");

double horas = fecha2.Subtract(fecha1).TotalHours;
```

[TimeSpan.TotalHours Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalhours?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Como podria convertir mi DateTime para usarlo con TimeSpan?

Comment: no entendi la pregunta, porque quieres convertir el datetime a timespan? si quieres obtener la hora de una fecha solo aplica formato usando el fecha.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), use la HH porque es una hora en formato 24hs sino puedes usad hh que es la hora en forma 12hs, pero deberaa agregar el "tt" para tener el AM o PM

Comment: Lo de convertir lo digo, porque necesito hacer lo siguiente.Por ejemplo, tengo las 13:45:00 menos las 12:25:00 y necesito que el resultado sea 80 minutos. Como las horas las tengo guardadas en un DateTime, pensaba en usar un TimeSpan para hacer la operacion ya mencionada

Comment: si realizas la resta de dos fechas para obtener los minutos usarias la propiedad TotalMinutes, si vas a guardar horario entonces usa el TimeSpan directamente

Comment: Aun restando las fechas con el ejemplo del codigo que me diste, sigo sin obtener el resultado

Comment: puedes editar la pregunta y poner el codigo que estas utilizando

Comment: Ya lo hice, agradeceria mucho tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el TimeSpan para la diferencia de horas de la siguiente manera:

```
TimeSpan diferenciaHoras = new TimeSpan();
DateTime fechaInicio = new DateTime();
fechaInicio = DateTime.Parse("12:25:00");

DateTime fechaLlegada = new DateTime();
fechaLlegada = DateTime.Parse("13:30:00");

diferenciaHoras = fechaLlegada - fechaInicio;
int horas = diferenciaHoras.Hours;
double horasTotales = diferenciaHoras.TotalHours;
```

En este ejemplo, entre las 12:25 y las 13:30 hay una hora con 5 minutos. La propiedad TotalHours te dará el resultado de 1.083 que es la hora mas 0.083 horas que equivalen a los 5 minutos.

Si lo necesitas en minutos, entonces utilizas la propiedad TotalMinutes o multiplicas las horas obtenidas por 60.

```
double minutos = diferenciaHoras.TotalMinutes;
```

O

```
double minutos = horasTotales * 60;
```